# Cryptography that lets you conceal a secret, but also alerts others of the exposure of the concealed secret?

Tags: encryption, cryptocurrency

Is there such a cryptography where I can prove that someone decrypted an encrypted string? Say I wanted to attach a Bitcoin private key in some type of digital container, but in order to open this digital container, I would need to break a digital seal.

I'm basically trying to find a digital equivalent of how a security wax seal works to make a letter tamperproof:

[image]

What is the digital equivalent of this? I can write down a bitcoin private key in the envelope and have a wax seal on it. But how do I do this via email?

Comment: If I break AES or DSA I'll not tell anybody!

Comment: One fundamental obstacle to this is that for (classical) computation, digital information is *cloneable*. In particular, if you give me such a digital object $D$, I can copy this to get $D'$. Then, even if I break the "wax seal" on $D'$, this is now not connected to $D$. This isn't to say that it is impossible, but that any method must deal with the above obstacle. For example, in the quantum setting the "cloning" arguments break down, but this may be less interesting for your purpose.

Comment: Looks like this would require a centralized server in order to detect if a digital lock was opened or not.

Comment: I agree with the above comments, this seems to require either a trusted central authority, or the use of quantum computation.

Comment: Note that knowing if someone accessed the secret is quite different than making them unable to modify it! (and as a sidenote, wax seals weren't perfect, either)

Comment: how do we get to use quantum computation? Is it ready yet?

Comment: It's perfectly ready for use in theoretical constructions, it's just the real world which is lagging behind :)